# WPF DispatcherUnhandledException with .NET Core 3.0 Preview 6 on non-english operating system

Tags: wpf, .net-core, preview, visual-studio-2019

After update from .NET Core 3.0 preview 5 to preview 6 simple WPF controls throws DispatcherUnhandledException on German operation systems.

> Example: Trying to input text into a TextBox results in "Requested value **'BILDAUF'** was not found."

The same application runs on English OS without any problem.

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

With the following work around the application runs:

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
   public App()
   {
      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
   }
}
```

Changing the CurrentUICulture for example to "fr-FR" throws

"Requested value **'SUPPRIMER'** was not found."